# How to show a preference at center of the screen?

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, android-10.0

I am creating an android project. I am using `PreferenceCategory` in my `PreferenceScreen`. My layout for `PreferenceScreen` looks like this.

```
<PreferenceCategory app:title="ABC"
        app:key="P1"
        />
<PreferenceCategory app:title="ABC"
        app:key="P2"
        />
<PreferenceCategory app:title="ABC"
        app:key="P3"
        />
<PreferenceCategory app:title="ABC"
        app:key="P4"
        />
<PreferenceCategory app:title="ABC"
        app:key="P5"
        />
```

In `PreferenceCategory` `P2` and `P3` I am adding `Preferences` using `addPreference()` function.
What I want is to show `PreferenceCategory` `P4` and `P5` in centre(horizontally and vertically) of remaining screen.

I searched on internet about this but didn't find any `gravity` related attribute for `PreferenceCategory`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: My suggestion would be not using a preference screen and rather designing your own layout. Because preference screens are supposed to be made scrollable if the content is bigger than the screen. It mostly has a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView` to show the content which blocks you from placing any gravity on the child view.

Comment: The behaviors can still be implemented manually, however it looks like you need to change your whole structure.

Comment: I added a custom layout for preference category with a single textview in it and with attribiute  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical  but  textview comes after much scrolling

Comment: Hello. I didn't get how to use custom layout as it is my settings activity and i have to use preferences. How can I use preferences outside preference screen

Comment: what furkan is proposing is that you dont use the preference framework at all and just create your own activity for it. using a SharedPreferences editor you can achieve the same that your preferences achieve but with a lot more work haha

Comment: might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55371906/androidx-preference-screen-shifted-off-center

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul . you were right. Finally had to design my own layout instead of using preferences. Thank you guys for help.